# sort NSArray of UIImagerview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, uiimageview, nsarray

i want to sort NSArray of UIImageView according their frame?

i try for NSSortDescriptor but when i write key=@"frame" unrecognized selector error occur.
please tell me how to sort my array.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own comparator function and define custom sorting behavior by using [NSArray sortedArrayUsingSelector method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:)

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your project

```
NSArray * myArray =  @[

             [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 200, 100)],
              [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100)],
              [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 40, 50, 100)],
              [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 100)],
              [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 67)]

    ];


    myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIImageView * view1, UIImageView * view2) {

        if (! CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

    }];
```